# ssh client using python socket

Tags: python

how can i  write ssh client using python socket?

Subhan

Comment: Don't you think this question is *slightly* too general? Is it, dare I say, homework?

Comment: Don't even try if you ask such questions.

Comment: Something that you can EASILY google... Honestly...

Answer (score 6):

I haven't used it yet - but why don't you try [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/)?

Comment: Iam using windows
i install paramiko,but it's giving some error

Comment: It's usually helpful to describe "some error" when asking for help.

Comment: Paramiko uses PyCrypto which is controlled software, http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml should resolve the primary dependancy issues.

Answer (score 4):

Of course it is! In fact it is already implemented!!

See [`twisted.conch`](http://twistedmatrix.com/users/z3p/files/conch-talk.html) - the implementation is pure python using sockets!

Answer (score 0):

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('<host>', username='null', password='p455w0rd')
```

This is a simple example using, Paramiko. It would be best if you could elaborate on the error that Paramiko is giving you. If it is an error installing I recommend trying "pip install paramiko", or you can just try to re-download from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paramiko/.

Comment: You can also write SSH servers using paramiko.